# Redirect to Show page after search - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having trouble redirecting to a model show page after a user submits a search. The search happens two ways. It searches the database to see if the ETF is there. If not, it scrapes a webpage for the data and saves it in the database. The route for the search form is http://localhost:3000/search_etfs Here is the controller:

class EtfsController < ApplicationController

```
  def search
    if params[:etf]
      @etf = Etf.find_by_ticker(params[:etf])
      @etf ||= Scraper.new_from_lookup(params[:etf])
    end
    if @etf.present?
      redirect_to @etf
    else
      puts "ETF was not found."
    end
  end

  def show
    @etf = Etf.find(params[:id])
    @top_holdings = @etf.top_holdings
    @country_weights = @etf.country_weights
    @sector_allocations = @etf.sector_allocations
  end

end
```

The terminal implies it should be redirecting to the corresponding ETF show page. Yet the webpage does not go to the new corresponding URL

```
Started GET "/etfs/2" for ::1 at 2017-04-30 11:27:34 -0400
Processing by EtfsController#show as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"2"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Etf Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "etfs".* FROM "etfs" WHERE "etfs"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]

  Rendering etfs/show.html.erb within layouts/application

  TopHolding Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "top_holdings" WHERE "top_holdings"."etf_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["etf_id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  TopHolding Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "top_holdings".* FROM "top_holdings" WHERE "top_holdings"."etf_id" = ?  [["etf_id", 2]]
  SectorAllocation Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "sector_allocations" WHERE "sector_allocations"."etf_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["etf_id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SectorAllocation Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "sector_allocations".* FROM "sector_allocations" WHERE "sector_allocations"."etf_id" = ?  [["etf_id", 2]]
  CountryWeight Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "country_weights" WHERE "country_weights"."etf_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["etf_id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CountryWeight Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "country_weights".* FROM "country_weights" WHERE "country_weights"."etf_id" = ?  [["etf_id", 2]]

  Rendered etfs/show.html.erb within layouts/application (14.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 148ms (Views: 130.6ms | ActiveRecord: 1.4ms)
```

Here are the routes:

```
  root 'welcome#index'
  get 'search_etfs', to: 'etfs#search'
  get '/etfs/:id', to: 'etfs#show', as: 'etf'
```

Ideally, I would make the URL be something like http://localhost:3000/search_etfs?=SPY that would display the showpage for the searched for ETF.

To add in more information in response to @Robikul:

My search form is done through ajax:

```
<%= form_tag search_etfs_path, remote: true, method: :get, id: 'etf-lookup-form' do %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From you log `Processing by EtfsController#show as JS` it seems this is an `ajax request`. The format requested is `js` not `html` that's why the `redirect` not working.

You can create a `search.js.erb` file to serve if successful, handling the redirect through javascript with `window.location = "etf/<%=@etf.id%>"`. Your controller must have the `@etf` variable available.

Or you can try the following snippet in the replace of  `redirect_to @etf` in your controller

```
render js: "window.location = '#{etf_path(@eft)}'"
```

Comment: Thanks rokibul. How would I set this to render dynamically based on the ETF? I.E. be able able to redirect to /etf/1, /etf/2, /etf/3, etc?

Comment: I have edited the answer according your query, please take a look.